# how should i resolve firebase-analytics kt in build.gradle of the project one

Tags: firebase, flutter-dependencies

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

what changes shall i do